# Jupyter fails to start outside home directory

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, file-not-found

I did a fresh install of Anaconda 3.7 and tried opening a Jupyter notebook by doing the following:

1. Uninstalled Anaconda 3.6.
2. Deleted all anaconda, jupyter and python keys in the registry.
3. Deleted all anaconda, jupyter and python files and folders on the file system.
4. Rebooted.
5. Installed Anaconda 3.7 64-bit (on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit).  I ticked the "add to path" option in the installer.
6. Open PowerShell.
7. Start jupyter notebook using `jupyter notebook` command.
8. Try opening a notebook by selecting it in the browser.

I get the following error:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Tom Oakley> cd \code
PS C:\code> jupyter notebook
[I 09:57:26.662 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 09:57:26.662 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Anaconda3.7\share\jupyter\lab
[I 09:57:26.678 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\code
[I 09:57:26.678 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 09:57:26.678 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=5727bc46546f81bc6d795a7516f2758bfb01bdc764a47430
[I 09:57:26.678 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:57:26.725 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=5727bc46546f81bc6d795a7516f2758bfb01bdc764a47430
[I 09:57:27.787 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[W 09:57:38.081 NotebookApp] Notebook sandbox/parallel.ipynb is not trusted
[I 09:57:38.628 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 5296c75b-0bbe-45d9-897a-0d74a6a01dba
C:\code\sandbox
['.git', '.ipynb_checkpoints', '.mypy_cache', 'animation_example.py', 'parallel.ipynb', '__pycache__']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 557, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'test.py' -> 'test_dir.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 16, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "C:\code\sandbox\copy.py", line 9, in <module>
    shutil.move('test.py', 'test_dir.py')
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 571, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.py'
[I 09:57:41.612 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
C:\code\sandbox
['.git', '.ipynb_checkpoints', '.mypy_cache', 'animation_example.py', 'parallel.ipynb',  '__pycache__']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 557, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'test.py' -> 'test_dir.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 16, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "C:\code\sandbox\copy.py", line 9, in <module>
    shutil.move('test.py', 'test_dir.py')
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 571, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.py'
[I 09:57:44.673 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
C:\code\sandbox
['.git', '.ipynb_checkpoints', '.mypy_cache', 'animation_example.py', 'parallel.ipynb',  '__pycache__']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 557, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'test.py' -> 'test_dir.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 16, in <module>
    from copy import deepcopy
  File "C:\code\sandbox\copy.py", line 9, in <module>
    shutil.move('test.py', 'test_dir.py')
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 571, in move
    copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 257, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Anaconda3.7\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.py'
```

Updating the packages with `conda update --all` makes no difference.

Using `jupyter lab` gives the same error.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

I filed a [bug with the Jupyter project](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4229).

### Versions

```
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py37_0
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py37_0
jupyterlab                0.35.3                   py37_0
jupyterlab_launcher       0.13.1                   py37_0
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                    py37_0
```

Comment: Open you jupyter notebook at this location and then try again `PS C:\Users\Tom Oakley>jupyter notebook`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Starting `jupyter notebook` in my home directory works but sometimes I have to work on notebooks that are not under my home directory.  Trying `jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=C:\code\sandbox` gives me the same error.

Comment: Once you open the jupyter notebook in home directory . You can create new python file after going to another directory from jupyter notebook

Comment: I tried what you recommended but I can't get to `C\code\sandbox` if I started jupyter notebook in `C:\Users\Tom Oakley` because I can't go up to a parent directory from within the jupyter landing page.

Comment: Do you know why it works under Anaconda 3.6 but not 3.7?  If you could give me a clue, maybe I could find a workaround.

Comment: Try this once: 1.Open Anaconda prompt
Go to C:\Users\your_name
Write jupyter trust untitled.ipynb
Then, write jupyter notebook

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184105/discussion-between-shubham-agrawal-and-blokeley).

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:                                                                     1. Open Anaconda prompt
2. Go to C:\Users\your_name
3. Write `jupyter trust untitled.ipynb`
4. Then, write `jupyter notebook`

Comment: I tried: 1. Open Anaconda prompt; 2. I was already in my home directory; 3. `jupyter trust C:\code\sandbox` and got `PermissionError: [Errno 3] Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working after I just did `conda update --all`.

The new versions are:

```
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py37_7
jupyter_client            5.2.4                    py37_0
jupyter_console           6.0.0                    py37_0
jupyter_core              4.4.0                    py37_0
jupyterlab                0.35.3                   py37_0
jupyterlab_launcher       0.13.1                   py37_0
jupyterlab_server         0.2.0                    py37_0
```